# TFS doesn't show last version

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I work with TFS 2012 in Visual Studio 2010. I create project. My friend get this version and add folder and check in. After that I get last version . In Source Control Explorer I can see this folder. Also I can see in local folder. But I don't see this folder in Solution Explorer. I have tried to Check out Project.sln, and I see message, that file last version but in solution explorer I'm nothing see. How this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should execute a Get Latest Version in Source Control Explorer.

After this the Solution Explorer should refresh automatically!

If it won't work, i think you should try Get Specific Version and check both CheckBoxes of the bottom of the Dialog.

But if you use the second Option you have to get safe that you have checked in alle changes, otherwise they are getting overwritten.

Comment: Incorrect. The second option reads "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version". There is no option to select that overwrites any checked out files.